# Timer ends but displays 0:01

Tags: javascript, timer, clearinterval

The code works fine but when the timer ends it displays 0:01 and not 0:00.

```
<html>

  <body>   
    <div>
        <span id="time6" class="timer">00:06</span>
        
        <br/>
    
          <button onclick="start6Timer()" class="start-button">start</button>
    
          <button onclick="resetTimer()" class="reset-button">reset</button>
          
          <p>To reset press reset and then start.</p>
    </div>
  </body>

  <script>
    let timerId;
    function startTimer(duration, display) {
      var timer = duration,
        minutes, seconds;
      timerId = setInterval(function() {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
          timer = duration;
        }
        
        if (timer == 0){
            stopTimer();
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
    
   function start6Timer() {
          var sixSeconds = 60 * 0.1,
          display = document.querySelector('#time6');
          startTimer(sixSeconds, display);
        };
        
        function resetTimer() {
              clearInterval(timerId);
            }
            
        function stopTimer() {
            clearInterval(timerId);
            }
        
  </script>
</html>
```

I need it display it when any timer ends, I have multiple timers using the startTimer Function but I'm stumped on how to display 0:00 when any of the timers finish.

here is a link to a W3school Tryit Editor with my code: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GJRWXNYJMDYS

Answer (score 1):

You need to rearrange the code a little bit. Especially your `setInterval` part:

```
timerId = setInterval(function() {

  if (--timer < 0) {
    timer = duration;
  }

  minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
  seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

  minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
  seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

  display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

  if (timer == 0){
    stopTimer();
  }
}, 1000);
```

The issue is that you are calling `timer--` after calculating minutes and seconds. What you need to do, however, is to calculate this *before* `timer--`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you stop the timer (timer == 0) you don't refresh the display one more time. Change your code like so

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
      var timer = duration,
        minutes, seconds;
      timerId = setInterval(function() {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
          stopTimer();
          timer = duration;
        }
      }, 1000);
    }
```